# all pairs $(p,q)$ of prime numbers which $p>q$ and $\frac{(p+q)^{p+q}(p-q)^{p-q}-1}{(p+q)^{p-q}(p-q)^{p+q}-1}$is an integer.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find all pairs $(p,q)$ of prime numbers which $p>q$ and
$$\frac{(p+q)^{p+q}(p-q)^{p-q}-1}{(p+q)^{p-q}(p-q)^{p+q}-1}$$is an integer.

Does anyone have idea on how to solve this?

I did:
$(p,q)=(3,2) $ satisfies.
By bounding, we get $p<3q$
$ (p + q)^{p - q} - 1 \le (p + q)^{p - q}(p - q)^{p + q} - 1 \le (p + q)^{2q} - (p - q)^{2q} \le (p + q)^{2q} - 1 .$

Any solution?

Comment: You tagged as contest-math. Please say what contest and what year.

Comment: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2017SL.pdf page 80

Answer (score 1):

This is IMO Shortlist 2017 N5. You can find plenty solutions on the AoPS page: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1671301p10632380.